# Testing errors with Test::Warn thrown by a loop

Tags: perl, testing

I have the following subroutine that creates a database:

```
sub create_db {
  my $self = shift;
  my $name = shift;
  $self->dbh->do("create database $name")
}
```

This subroutine is called by this one which generates several databases in a loop:

```
sub add_all_databases {
  my $self = shift;

  foreach my $year (@{$self->years}) {
    my $name = DB_NAME_PREFIX . $year;
    $self->create_db($name);
  }
}
```

Perl generates a warning if a database already exists:

```
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Can't create database 'db_2014'; database exists
```

I want to create a test to check that that the warning is thrown when a database already exists. I attempted that with this test:

```
 use Test::Warn

 warnings_like {$i->add_all_databases} qr{do failed}, 'throws error if database exists';
```

However, it does not seem to work. I get output like this from my test script:

```
not ok 17 - throws error if database exists
#   Failed test 'throws error if database exists'
#   at ./importer.t line 69.
# found warning: DBD::mysql::db do failed: Can't create database 'db_2000'; database exists at /home/steve/perl/perl-lib/DB.pm line 46, <DATA> line 1.
# found warning: DBD::mysql::db do failed: Can't create database 'db_2001'; database exists at /home/steve/perl/perl-lib/DB.pm line 46, <DATA> line 1.
# found warning: DBD::mysql::db do failed: Can't create database 'db_2002'; database exists at /home/steve/perl/perl-lib/DB.pm line 46, <DATA> line 1.
# expected to find warning: (?^:do failed)
```

How do I properly write a test that will pass?

Comment: OK, I see now that if I am trying to generate 3 databases, I need to have `qr{do failed}` in an array reference 3 times. I guess I need to anticipate how many databases will be created in my test, unless there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to `warnings_like` should be a reference to an array containing exactly as many elements as there are warnings:

```
warnings_like { warn $_ for 1..3 } [qr/1/, qr/\d/, qr/[345]/];
```

As an aside, creating multiple databases with different numeric suffixes is a major code smell. Generally it would be better to have a single database with a column for the year.

Comment: OK, so I'm trying to generate 18 databases (yeah, I agree, probably not  good idea). So I got this `warnings_like {$i->add_all_databases} [qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},qr{do failed},    qr{do failed}], 'throws error if database exists';`

Test passes but this is super ugly. What's the best way to rewrite this?

Comment: @StevieD use the `x` operator. `warnings_like { ... } [ ( qr{foo} ) x 18 ]`

Comment: @StevieD `my @warnings; push @warnings, qr/foo/ for 1..18; warnings_like { ... } \@warnings;` or `my @warnings = map qr/foo/, 1..18;`